# Regex using PHP, any non-zero number containing the digits 0-9

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this regex:

```
/^[0-9]+$/i
```

Used in this code:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/i', $var);
```

I want the following to be true:
$var = 1;
$var = 50;
$var = 333;

And the following to be false:
$var = 0;
$var = 01;
$var = 'abc';

I think what I have works so far except for the "0" part..?

I went through this guide (http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-regular-expression.html) but was unable to come up with a complete answer.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just as a PS: You don't need the `i` modifier, if you aren't using any letters ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

Means: A non-zero digit followed by an arbitrary number of digits (including zero).

Answer (score 4):

just check for a non zero digit first then any number of other digits

```
preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/', $var);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

or

```
/^(?!0)[0-9]+$/
```

Either one of these should be fine. The first one should be more or less self-explanatory, and the second one uses a [zero-width negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure the first digit isn't 0.

**Note that regex isn't designed for numeric parsing.** There are other ways of doing it that will be faster and more flexible in terms of numeric format. For example:

```
if (is_numeric($val) && $val != 0)
```

...should pick up any nonzero number, including decimals and scientific notation.

Comment: Your last code doesn't match the regex (in many many ways) :) E.g. the regex doesn't match 0xABC or 0.034e-19 or 01.

Comment: @NikiC - That's a fair point, although the last code (since edited) would have blocked those because of the leading zero. However, the regex would have blocked 1.234, and the PHP I posted wouldn't. I intended the last part just as an acknowledgement that regex isn't for number parsing, so I've edited to make that more clear.

Comment: The $val != 0 checks for zero values, not for a leading zero. Furthermore the last thing you normally want is to allow people to enter a number in scientific notation, hex or oct. Especially if you need to explain to them afterwards why their "012" got a "10" instead of a "12".

Comment: @NikiC - The PHP code is just an example of numeric parsing, not meant to be equivalent to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by forcing the first digit to be different from 0 with `'/^[1-9][0-9]*$/'`

With your list of exemples:

```
foreach (array('1', '50', '333', '0', '01', 'abc') as $var) {
  echo $var.': '.(preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/', $var) ? 'true' : 'false')."\n";
}
```

This script gives the following results:

```
$ php test.php
1: true
50: true
333: true
0: false
01: false
abc: false
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses. They're not doing anything in this case.